# R column name in an object is being replaced by the object name

Tags: xml, r

Below is a code I am using to read an xml file and create a data frame out of the attributes in the xml file. However, I am small issue with the code. [Here](http://www.filedropper.com/plans_1) is a sample for the data.

When I convert the first list named `attribact` into a dataframe named `k1`, the column named `x` in the list is changed to `k1`. The same thing happens with the last line of the code `data1 <- cbind(k1,k2)`. Here, the column name `k1` (from earlier step) is changed to `data1`  In other words, one of the column names in the list is being replaced by the object name the list is being assigned to.

```
plans <- xmlParse(file1)
idNodes <- getNodeSet(plans, "//person[@id]")
ids <- lapply(idNodes, function(x) xmlAttrs(x)['id'])
attribact <- vector("list", length(ids)*14)
k <- 1
for (i in 1:length(ids))
{
  act <- xpathApply(idNodes[[i]], path = paste("//person[@id=", as.numeric(ids[[i]]),"]//plan[@selected='yes']//act|leg", sep=""), xmlAttrs)
  for (j in 1:length(act))
  {
    attribact[[k]] <- c(act[[j]],ids[[i]])
    k <- k+1    
  }
}
attribact <- attribact[attribact!='NULL']
k1 <- t(as.data.frame(attribact))
data1 <- k1
```

Comment: Are you sure all the code and a figure are necessary? Couldn't you provide us with three lines of data and minimal code to reproduce the (one) problem (at a time)?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik There are two reasons. First, I did not know if the later steps in the code were affected by some of the earlier steps. Second, I want to speed up my code and so thought presenting the full code might help me get some advice on the performance.

Comment: I shortened the post. But, the data is many lines long (even for a single case). So, I just posted the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are better ways to do it, but to give you a quick answer that should work re-using your code, juste change the end

*Your code*

```
library(XML)
plans <- xmlParse(file1)
idNodes <- getNodeSet(plans, "//person[@id]")
ids <- lapply(idNodes, function(x) xmlAttrs(x)['id'])
attribact <- vector("list", length(ids)*14)
k <- 1
for (i in 1:length(ids))
{
  act <- xpathApply(idNodes[[i]], path = paste("//person[@id=", as.numeric(ids[[i]]),"]//plan[@selected='yes']//act|leg", sep=""), xmlAttrs)
  for (j in 1:length(act))
  {
    attribact[[k]] <- c(act[[j]],ids[[i]])
    k <- k+1    
  }
}
attribact <- attribact[attribact!='NULL']
```

*Then do*

```
data <- t(do.call(cbind, attribact))
```

Is it what you want?

```
head(data)
#>      type   link    x               y               start_time end_time  
#> [1,] "home" "21258" "334867.243653" "3126570.70778" "03:00:00" "15:07:00"
#> [2,] "shop" "13904" "332634.86999"  "3127078.96383" "15:12:00" "16:21:00"
#> [3,] "shop" "14129" "331666.364904" "3129306.48785" "16:25:00" "17:37:00"
#> [4,] "home" "21258" "334867.243653" "3126570.70778" "17:45:00" "26:59:00"
#> [5,] "home" "21256" "334598.361546" "3126269.05167" "03:00:00" "07:56:00"
#> [6,] "work" "14057" "335957.065395" "3128105.16619" "08:04:00" "10:28:00"
#>      id        
#> [1,] "10000061"
#> [2,] "10000061"
#> [3,] "10000061"
#> [4,] "10000061"
#> [5,] "10000302"
#> [6,] "10000302"
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. Can you shed some light on why the object name is replacing the column name? Also, you mentioned about better ways to achieve this. Can you provide some direction on this? Initially, my post had 2 questions where the second question asks for improvements to my code as it is painfully slow for my purposes. However, I had to shorten it owing to comments by mods.

Comment: Ok, I see the issue. Even my code gets the same result as yours. But, when I click on the created dataset from the Rstudio environment and display it in Rstudio, the column named "x" is being displayed as the object name.